# Telegram бот не отправляет картинку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Читал документацию, но все равно не получается реализовать отправку картинки ботом.

Код:

```
import telebot
import random

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ХХХ")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):

# keybord
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton(" Рандомное число")
item2 = types.KeyboardButton(" Как дела?")
item3 = types.KeyboardButton("Задача")

markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ — <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный в развлекательных целях, который не несет смысловой нагрузки.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode = 'html', reply_markup = markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
if message.chat.type == 'private':
    if message.text == ' Рандомное число':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))
    elif message.text == ' Как дела?':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не хорошо", callback_data='bad')

        markup.add(item1, item2)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, твои как, {0.first_name}?'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)



    elif message.text == 'Задача':
        photo = open('p.png', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, 'rb')

        #file_id = "img/kot1.png"
        #bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, file_id)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
 bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

После запуска бота и нажатии кнопки "Задача" выходит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сделать это различными вариантами, но упирается в эту ошибку.

Возможно неправильно задан путь к этой картинки, картинку я разместил здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Накиньте, пожалуйста, вариантов, как можно это исправить.

Переместил в папку с `main.py`, но все осталось по-прежнему:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если картинка лежит там же где и скрипт - указывайте просто имя файла картинки. если картинка лежит в другом каталоге - указывайте данный каталог/имя файла картинки. пример `static/p.png`, но на скриншоте не совсем ясно где лежит ваш скрипт.

можете создать  каталоге где лежит скрипт папку `img` положить туда все картинки и использовать `img/%name_file%'

Comment: А как узнать в каком месте лежит скрипт? И скрипт - это "main.py"? Просто я только начинаю изучать и не совсем понимаю где и как

Comment: скрипт - это `main.py`

Answer (score 3):

Допустим у Вас вот такая структура проекта:

```
super_bot
    default.png
    script.py
```

в таком случае достаточно указать только имя файла:

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('default.png', 'rb'))
```

если изображение находится в другом каталоге, например:

```
super_bot
    img
       default.png
    script.py
```

тогда укажите путь к файлу:

```
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('img/default.png', 'rb'))
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/nG9nObVSQ6k?t=145

Comment: Если ответ является решением, отметьте его таковым. Это поможет другим участникам.

Answer (score 1):

Держи

```
elif message.text == 'Задача':
     photo = open('venv/Lib/site-packges/telebot/static/p.png', 'rb')
     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

*Если ответ помог, ставь галочку слева от этого ответа*

Comment: Все равно вылазит эта же ошибка

Comment: Изменил ответ, попробуй

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: ну тогда перетащи фото в папку где лежит твой main.py и поменяй на photo = open('p.png', 'rb')

Comment: Сделал так, но не помогло, скриншоты прикрепил в самое начало. Посмотрите, может я не так сделал..